# Excel Powerpivot/Slicer: Dynamically choose chart variable

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I just started using powerpivot.

Currently I have slicers that filter based on the values of one variable, but I also want to create a pivotchart where the user can select what variable to graph. Is there a way to populate one slicer with variables from a powerpivot table?

I have a handful of variables that a user might want to look at, and I do not want to have one graph for each variable.

I hope this makes sense. Any suggestions? Thanks & Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to this that is pretty straightforward and although it's not perfect as it doesn't work dynamically, I've used it very successfully in this kind of situation where you are talking about selecting between a well defined set of metrics.

The technique makes use of a disconnected table to drive the slicer with the final formula using the selected value to decide which measure to use.

Lets say you have 2 measures `[Sales]` and `[Profit]` you want to choose between. You create a table in your PowerPivot model called, say, 'SlicerTbl' with a single column called Measure that has 2 rows 'Sales' and 'Profit'. No relationship is required. (the table can be called whatever you like btw).

You can then write a 3rd measure that enables you to choose which measure to use:

```
=
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( SlicerTbl[Measure] ),
    SWITCH (
        VALUES ( SlicerTbl[Measure] ),
        "Measure 1", [Measure 1],
        "Measure 2", [Measure 2]
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

This basically checks to see if the slicer has a single value and if so uses VALUES() to return the selected value - because of the initial clause this can only ever be a single row. This means it returns blank in the case of multiple selections.

The SWITCH() is basically an elegant IF() that is easy to scale so I don't see why you couldn't do this with 20+ measures very quickly.

Hope this helps, I created a stupidly simple example here: [Example Model](http://1drv.ms/1qqnxZ7)

Comment: Thanks @jacob I tried looking at your example model, however it says the data model is in an external source and not connected (and thus I cannot look at the power pivot table).

I'm a confused on how to use the slicer to choose the variable in the original datatable.

Comment: i'm also trying to follow: http://eriksvensen.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/use-slicers-to-select-the-facts-in-a-pivot-chart/

but get caught up on creating the 2nd pivot table

Comment: damn onedrive - click on 'onedrive' at the top and download the file. Let me know if you have an issue. His technique is basically the same as mine but his explanation is a little verbose.

Comment: thanks. i still had issues with the excel file b/c i'm using 2013 - but between your answer and the wordpress it is now functional